# Jolt transform for json to json remove key value and add split string value

Tags: json, jolt

I need to use jolt transform to do the below JSON transformation:

Need to remove the keys:

`src-port` and `tx-interval`

To change the names of the keys:

`vdevice-host-name` to `local-host-name`

To split at ***key:value*** the string value of the key `vdevice-datakey`:

***example***:

`"vdevice-dataKey":"10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-internet-ipsec"` to

`"remote-system-ip : 10.157.96.2"` and `"remote-color" : "internet"`

Input JSON is:

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
        "dst-ip": "10.161.25.182",
        "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.1",
        "color": "mpls",
        "src-port": 12346,
        "createTimeStamp": 1623334401569,
        "system-ip": "10.157.96.2",
        "dst-port": 12346,
        "site-id": 141011085,
        "transitions": 0,
        "local-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
        "local-color": "mpls",
        "detect-multiplier": "7",
        "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-internet-ipsec",
        "@rid": 168682,
        "vmanage-system-ip": "10.127.200.1",
        "proto": "ipsec",
        "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
        "state": "up",
        "tx-interval": 1000,
        "uptime-date": 1623334260000
    }, {
        "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
        "dst-ip": "10.162.45.94",
        "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.1",
        "color": "mpls",
        "src-port": 12346,
        "createTimeStamp": 1623334402985,
        "system-ip": "10.157.16.2",
        "dst-port": 12346,
        "site-id": 142011050,
        "transitions": 0,
        "vdevice-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
        "local-color": "mpls",
        "detect-multiplier": "7",
        "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.16.2-internet-ipsec",
        "@rid": 206290,
        "vmanage-system-ip": "10.127.200.1",
        "proto": "ipsec",
        "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
        "state": "up",
        "tx-interval": 1000,
        "uptime-date": 1623334260000
    }]
}
```

Output JSON is:

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
        "dst-ip": "10.161.25.182",
        "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.1",
        "color": "mpls",
        "createTimeStamp": 1623334401569,
        "system-ip": "10.157.96.2",
        "dst-port": 12346,
        "site-id": 141011085,
        "transitions": 0,
        "local-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
        "local-color": "mpls",
        "detect-multiplier": "7",
        "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.96.2-internet-ipsec",
        "@rid": 168682,
        "vmanage-system-ip": "10.127.200.1",
        "proto": "ipsec",
        "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
        "state": "up",
        "uptime-date": 1623334260000,
        "remote-system-ip":"10.157.96.2",
        "remote-color":"internet"
    }, {
        "src-ip": "10.161.25.170",
        "dst-ip": "10.162.45.94",
        "vdevice-name": "10.127.200.1",
        "color": "mpls",
        "createTimeStamp": 1623334402985,
        "system-ip": "10.157.16.2",
        "dst-port": 12346,
        "site-id": 142011050,
        "transitions": 0,
        "local-host-name": "AEXI630_XITO098_E_COUNTRY_2081",
        "local-color": "mpls",
        "detect-multiplier": "7",
        "vdevice-dataKey": "10.127.200.1-mpls-10.157.16.2-internet-ipsec",
        "@rid": 206290,
        "vmanage-system-ip": "10.127.200.1",
        "proto": "ipsec",
        "lastupdated": 1623334401562,
        "state": "up",
        "uptime-date": 1623334260000,
        "remote-system-ip":"10.157.16.2",
        "remote-color":"internet"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consecutively apply **shift** transformation in order to generate new elements to be rendered, then **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation in order to split the string into pieces to determine *remote-system-ip* and *remote-color* values, and then **remove** transformation to remove the desired keys along with the lately generated keys such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "vdevice-host-name": "&2.[&1].local-host-name",
          "local-host-name": "&2.[&1].&",
          "*": "&2.[&1].&",
          "@(0,vdevice-dataKey)": "&2.[&1].remote"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "remote": "=split('-', @(1,&))",
          "remote-system-ip": "@(1,remote[2])",
          "remote-color": "@(1,remote[3])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "src-port": "",
          "tx-interval": "",
          "remote": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```